Error in using mitmproxy's http module in python
I have a code that uses mitmproxy http function and it miserably fails here:
def main(stdscr):
    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='NetSour Network Analyzer')
        parser.add_argument('--proxy', action='store_true', help='Enable HTTPS decryption (BETA)')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        if args.proxy:
            print("WARNING: HTTPS decryption is in BETA. Use at your own risk.")
            from mitmproxy.tools.main import mitmdump
            >>>>mitmdump(['--scripts', __file__, '--set', 'block_global=false'])
            return
        if is_root():
            stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "[+] You are root.")
        else:
            stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "[-] You are not root.")
        stdscr.addstr(1, 0, "[+] Enter the interface name: ")
        curses.echo()
        interface = stdscr.getstr().decode()
        curses.noecho()

        packet_queue = Queue()
        sniff_thread = Thread(target=sniff_packets, args=(packet_queue, interface))
        sniff_thread.daemon = True
        sniff_thread.start()
        
        stdscr.addstr(3, 0, "[+] Starting NetSour...")
        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(1)
        
        display_packets(stdscr, packet_queue)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in main function: {str(e)}")


returning
return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 2447, in _signature_from_callable

raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: <ColorTable> is not a callable object
                                                                                         [19:36:20.886] HTTP(S) proxy listening at *:8080.
Error logged during startup, exiting...

I asked ChatGpt and it said it has something to do with an unknown function called ColorTables so i searched that, but it does nothing.

The error/exception is hard to read and make sense of. Maybe you can get rid of your exception handling and just let the exception propagate and terminate your program, then edit your question with the complete exception formatted in a [code block].

I suspect the problem is in code you haven’t shown. You’re attempting to use a single script as both a CLI script and as a mitmproxy script; this is somewhat hazardous as mitmproxy expects scripts to be formatted a certain way. You may be better off shipping a separate mitmproxy script, and putting any common code between the two scripts in a separate module.
